# Survival Analysis - Comparing Different Time Origin Events

Tags: survival

This may be a naive question but I am designing an experiment wherein I am collecting health data on individuals with the goal to use that data to predict the occurrence of hospitalizations. I am wondering if I can do this by defining different time origin event criteria from the different health data variables (eg. o2sat dipping below 85%, heart rate variability hitting 95%, etc) and looking at associated risk curves (using the time to hospitalization as the time variable). The idea is that the time origin events with the 'steeper' risk curves are the more immediate predictors of hospitalizations. Is this statistically sound?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV. How are you handling patients who meet both criteria?

Comment: Thank you! I am happy to be here, first time on this message board and it feels like a good community. To be honest, I hadn't thought much about that possibility. I guess at first blush I would treat them as independent events but doing some research, maybe it is appropriate to use multi-state modeling?

Comment: Note, you may want to consider doing logistic regression on hospitalization with a variable for O2 sats and one for HR variability. This looks at probability of hospitalization, but will allow you to assess contributions of each variable. You may also consider a proportional hazards model. Either way, I don't think a straight up Kaplan-Meier survival curve would be appropriate for capturing what it is you want.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you Todd - your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: After thinking about it, if you remove people who experience both (assuming the two events don't occur simultaneously... ) you could probably compare survival curves after diagnosis of people who only experience low O2 sats vs people who only experience high HR variability using a log-rank test. But even then, you might just be better to analyze median time to hospitalization after diagnosis. It's the interaction (if there are any, which I expect there will be) that muddies things.